# Trying to get text value from the text input field but it's logging to console as blank even though there is text in the field

Tags: javascript

Trying to initialize a map using the Google Maps API. Input the latitude and longitude for the center as numbers. Receiving an error that says they are not numebrs.

```js
// Grab the search box
let searchBox = document.getElementById('search-entry');
// Get the text entered by the user in the search box
let searchEntry = searchBox.value;
// Grab the search button
let searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');

// Function to split the search entry
function searchEntrySplitter() {
  let splitSearchEntry = searchEntry.split(" ");
  console.log(splitSearchEntry);
}

// Event listener for the submit button being pressed
searchButton.addEventListener('click', searchEntrySplitter, false)
```

```html
<div id="search-bar">

  <input type="text" id="search-entry">

  <button id="search-button" class="button">
        Search
      </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `let` statements are being executed when the page loads, i.e. when the user hasn't had the opportunity to set the values in the field.

Move the declarations for the variables that are being used to represent the user's input into the body of your primary functionality (`searchEntrySplitter()`) to pull the data from the search field when the button is clicked.

```js
// Grab the search button
let searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
// Function to split the search entry
function searchEntrySplitter() {
  // Grab the search box
  let searchBox = document.getElementById('search-entry');
  // Get the text entered by the user in the search box
  let searchEntry = searchBox.value;

  let splitSearchEntry = searchEntry.split(" ");
  console.log(splitSearchEntry);
}

// Event listener for the submit button being pressed
searchButton.addEventListener('click', searchEntrySplitter, false)
```

```html
<div id="search-bar">

  <input type="text" id="search-entry">

  <button id="search-button" class="button">
        Search
      </button>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you declared your `searchEntry` variable when the input had no content so the variable was set to a empty string when the DOM loaded. If you move the declaration for `searchEntry` to the click event's scope, it will be updated every time the button is pressed.

```js
// Grab the search box
let searchBox = document.getElementById('search-entry');
// Grab the search button
let searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');

// Function to split the search entry
function searchEntrySplitter() {
  // Get the text entered by the user in the search box
  let searchEntry = searchBox.value;
  let splitSearchEntry = searchEntry.split(" ");
  console.log(splitSearchEntry);
}

// Event listener for the submit button being pressed
searchButton.addEventListener('click', searchEntrySplitter, false)
```

```html
<div id="search-bar">

  <input type="text" id="search-entry">

  <button id="search-button" class="button">
        Search
      </button>

</div>
```